# Correct way to pass multiple options into a URL query string for a POST request

Tags: jsp, url, post, query-string

I have the following line of JSP code to create a URL query string for a POST request which searches for documents:

```
<c:set var="addQueryURL"><c:url value="/form/claim-query/new?claim-uid=${claimId}&type=claim"/></c:set>
```

As you can see, the type is equal to "claim", but for some documents in the database, the type is "check", so these don't get returned. A document can be either a claim or a check, but not both. So, what is the best way to enable the query string to request both "claims" and "checks"?

Would it be valid to write, for example:

```
<c:set var="addQueryURL"><c:url value="/form/claim-query/new?claim-uid=${claimId}&type=claim||$type=check"/></c:set>
```

or would I need to use some sort of wildcard or even a regular expression in order to pass both possible types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this - instead of editing the line of code that I included in the question, I edited the JSON code directly, where I could use an asterisk as a wildcard in the value for query-type:

```
<json:array name="constraints">
    <json:object>
        <json:property name="name" value="query-type"></json:property>
            <json:property name="value" value="c*"></json:property>
    </json:object>
</json:array>
```